# Infinite loop inserting docs in firebase after query in react

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to get how many documents there are in the `firestore` to get a correlative document of the day and then save a new document with React. For some reason when I execute the function to save the new document that causes that `firestore` to add the new record on an infinite loop. Probably I am doing something wrong. Can someone point me out with the error?

this is my function that saves the new document.

```
import { db } from '../utils/init-firebase'
import { collection, query, onSnapshot, Timestamp, addDoc, where } from "firebase/firestore"


export interface ProjectState {
    projectId: string,
    name: string;
}

const saveProject = async (project: ProjectState) => {
    try {
        const today = Timestamp.fromDate(new Date(new Date().getFullYear(), new Date().getMonth(), new Date().getDate()));
        const q = query(collection(db, 'projects'), where('created', '>=', today));
        let count = 0

        const unsubscribe = onSnapshot(q, (querySnapshot) => {
            count = querySnapshot.docs.length + 1;
            
            const date = new Date();
            const month = twoDigitDate(date.getMonth() + 1);
            const day = twoDigitDate(date.getDate());
            const year = date.getFullYear().toString().slice(-2)

            const projectId = `${month}${day}${year}${count > 0 ? '-' + count : ''}`;

            const projectDoc = collection(db, 'projects');
            return addDoc(projectDoc, {
                projectId,
                name: project.name
                created: Timestamp.now(),
            });
        })

    } catch (err) {
        console.log('Error creating project:', err)
    }
}

const twoDigitDate = (date: number) => {
    return date < 10 ? `0${date}` : date;
}


export default saveProject;
```

Comment: Is there any React code to share so we can see what is render looping?

Comment: It's can help you https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen#detach_a_listener

Comment: @DrewReese actually the problem is not the rendering, I render my form with no problem, after saving the project with the previous function, and redirecting to dashboard nothing happen in react, but when I go to `firebase` database I saw that it keeps adding the new project infinitely until I kill my react app. If I remove the `addDoc` the project is not saved but keeps querying the `snapshot` infinitely as well.

Comment: Ah, I see, then use the unsubscribe to unsubscribe from the snapshot subscription when you are done with it, or use one of the get methods that works only once.

Comment: unsubscribe works, but because saving the new project can take time, sometimes the subscription continues open until the insert document finishes. So I prefer to use the accepted response to the questions above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have infinite loop because of `onSnapshot()` is a listener listen all time collection and when new document appear triggers again with all documents in snapshoot + one extra you added. Insted of `onSnapshot()` use `getDocs()` function.

```js
import { collection, query, where, getDocs } from "firebase/firestore";

const q = query(collection(db, "cities"), where("capital", "==", true));

const querySnapshot = await getDocs(q);
querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
  // doc.data() is never undefined for query doc snapshots
  console.log(doc.id, " => ", doc.data());
});
```

Your function should lool like this ?

```js
const saveProject = async (project: ProjectState) => {
    try {
        const today = Timestamp.fromDate(new Date(new Date().getFullYear(), new Date().getMonth(), new Date().getDate()));
        const q = query(collection(db, 'projects'), where('created', '>=', today));
        let count = 0

        const querySnapshot = await getDocs(q)

        querySnapshot.forEach(doc => {
            // your code what ever you want to do.
        })

    } catch (err) {
        console.log('Error creating project:', err)
    }
}
```

I don't have any clue why you wanna make new docs in same collection according to old documents in this collection. You need to remember using only query you using now you will get max 100 documents.

Comment: `await getDocs` works like a charm, thank you so much!